# Implement functionality of @RequestBody in custom annotation

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have created a custom annotation `@JsonSchema` where I have implemented the functionality of `@RequestBody`. My annotation will always be used to read JSON from a web request. But I want to validate the JSON against a schema before letting it be passed further. For that I have a class that implements `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

Initially, my annotation was used only with a `String`, so it was easy for me to get the generic object from `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor#resolveArgument`, cast it to a string, validate it and then return it. But now I want to use my annotation with custom classes too.

So what I want to understand is how does `@RequestBody` cast the bind the JSON in the body of web request to compatible class. If I understand how that is happening, I can first extract the body as a string, do my validation and then bind the body to whatever class that has my annotation and return it.

My current implementation of `resolveArgument`

```
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    Object value =  getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor()
            .resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
    return value;
//      return validateJson(value, parameter); I need to pass a String here

}

// Using message converters to read from body of web request. Can I parse the message earlier than it is cast to the required object type?
private RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor getRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor() {

    if (requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor == null) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = requestMappingHandlerAdapter().getMessageConverters();
        requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(messageConverters);
    }
    return requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I came across something called `HttpMessageConverter`. Message converters are used to marshall and unmarshall Java Objects to and from JSON, XML, etc – over HTTP. There are some default converters out of which `StringHttpMessageConverter` is one. We can also add our own message converters. [Here](http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody.html) is a nice article explaining how to do that.

I got the default collection of message converters by invoking `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getMessageConverters`. I extracted the `StringHTTPMEssageConverter` out of it and invoked its `read` method to read the body as a String.

Here is the code:

```
if (requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor == null) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = requestMappingHandlerAdapter().getMessageConverters();
        requestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(messageConverters);
}

String body = null;
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = null;
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpInputMessage inputMessage = new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest);
if (messageConverters.get(1) instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter)
        stringHttpMessageConverter = (StringHttpMessageConverter) messageConverters.get(1);

try {
        body = stringHttpMessageConverter.read(String.class, inputMessage);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```